# gcc: How to avoid "used but never defined" warning for function defined in assembly

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, inline-assembly

For Reasons, I'm trying to use top-level assembly in GCC to define some static functions. However, since GCC doesn't "see" the body of those functions, it warns me that they are "used but never defined. A simple source code example could look like this:

```
/* I'm going to patch the jump offset manually. */
asm(".pushsection .slen,\"awx\",@progbits;"
    ".type test1, @function;"
    "test1: jmp 0;"
    ".popsection;");
/* Give GCC a C prototype: */
static void test(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* ... */
    test();
    /* ... */
}
```

And then,

```
$ gcc -c -o test.o test.c
test.c:74:13: warning: ‘test’ used but never defined [enabled by default]
 static void test(void);
             ^
```

How to avoid this?

Comment: Why can't you use `asm` *inside* function bodies?

Comment: Because I want to be able to have the address of the function, for use in several places.

Comment: Looks like you are reinventing Procedure Linkage Table of [dynamic linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linking)

Comment: Yes, that's one of my purposes; but it's not as if I can reuse the existing dynlinker in my own system. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`gcc` is being smart here because you've marked the function as static, meaning that it's expected be defined in this translation unit.

The first thing I'd do is get rid of the `static` specifier. This will permit (but not require) you to define it in a different translation unit so `gcc` will not be able to complain at the point of compilation.

That *may* introduce other problems, we'll have to see.

Comment: Oh, right. My knee-jerk reaction was that making the prototype non-`static` would export the symbol, but now that you mention it, that's probably not the case. :)

Comment: @Dolda2000, the _definition_ of a non-static function would make it visible, what you have there is a _declaration._ I suspect you'll find it's okay.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [symbol renaming pragma](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Symbol-Renaming-Pragmas.html)

```
 asm(".pushsection .slen,\"awx\",@progbits;"
      ".type test1_in_asm, @function;"
      "test1_in_asm: jmp 0;"
      ".popsection;");
 static void test(void);
 #pragma redefine_extname test test1_in_asm
```

or (using the same `asm` chunk above) the [asm labels](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html):

```
 static void test(void) asm("test1_in_asm");
```

or perhaps the [diagnostic pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) to selectively avoid the warning